# Как избежать подвисания программы во время ожидания выполнения другой через CreateProcess?

Tags: delphi, winapi

Запускаю программу Delphi, открывается форма, нажимаю на кнопку, происходит выполнение команды через `cmd.exe`. Мне нужно дождаться завершения ее выполнения. И пока команда не выполниться - у меня сама форма (программа) Delphi находится в замороженном состоянии. Мне нужно, чтобы сама форма (программа) Delphi - не была в замороженном состоянии. То есть её можно было передвигать. Как сделать, чтобы окно программы Delphi в процессе выполнения CMD.exe не застывало? То есть обработка в отдельном потоке.

```
var
  LCmd: string;
  LInfo: TStartupInfo;
  LPI: TProcessInformation;
begin
  // Заполняем структуры
  LCmd := 'cmd.exe ' + SPar;
  FillChar(LInfo, SizeOf(LInfo), 0);
  LInfo.cb := SizeOf(LInfo);
  LInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  LInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  // Запускаем программу
  Win32Check(CreateProcess(
    'cmd.exe',        // lpApplicationName,
    PChar(LCmd),      // lpCommandLine,
    nil,              // lpProcessAttributes,
    nil,              // lpThreadAttributes,
    False,            // bInheritHandles,
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW, // dwCreationFlags,
    nil,              // lpEnvironment,
    nil,              // lpCurrentDirectory,
    LInfo,            // lpStartupInfo,
    LPI               // lpProcessInformation
  ));
  try
    // Закрываем хендл главного потока (он нам не нужен)
    CloseHandle(LPI.hThread);
    // Ждем завершения процесса
    Win32Check(WaitForSingleObject(LPI.hProcess, INFINITE) <> WAIT_FAILED);
  finally
    // Закрываем хендл процесса
    CloseHandle(LPI.hProcess);
  end;
  ShowMessage('Программа завершена');
end;
```

Comment: Татьяна, если Вам необходимо просто запустить сторонний процесс и дальше работать в своей программе, то стандартного `ShellExecute` хватило бы с лихвой (основываясь на Вашем вчерашнем вопросе).

Comment: Что не устраивает, если просто убрать `WaitForSingleObject`?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Дополнила вопрос, то есть убрать вот эту строку -полностью : Win32Check(WaitForSingleObject(LPI.hProcess, INFINITE) <> WAIT_FAILED);

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Если так сделать то тогда сообщение  ShowMessage('Программа завершена'); Выскакивает сразу а не после завершения процесса.

Comment: Вот я и спрашиваю в первом же комментарии. Чего вы хотите добиться? Зачем вам ждать завершения программы?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Ну я сортирую текст через cmd + FINDSTR, большие объемы. И Мне нужно что бы форма была подвижна что бы в нужный момент остановить команду через кнопку. Обработчик кнопки остановить процессы и все остальное я сделала, но вот форма то зависает, а если убрать Win32Check(WaitForSingleObject(LPI.hProcess, INFINITE) <> WAIT_FAILED); то тогда сообщение ShowMessage('Программа завершена'); Выскакивает сразу а не после завершения процесса . А нужно после завершение процесса (Что бы знать что программа уже обработала и все сделала). Получается замкнутый круг ? :(.

Comment: Так. Уже ближе. А как вы получаете результат?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Вот так: /C FINDSTR /L " запрос" 1.txt > Rezultat_01.txt. Где (1.txt) это файл где искать находится в папке с программой. Rezultat_01.txt. - сам результат тоже сохраняется в папку самой программы. Ну и /C - Выход из cmd.exe после выполнения команды.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы дождаться завершения программы не замораживая интерфейс, нужно делать ожидание в отдельном потоке. А потом уведомить основной поток о завершении операции

```
type
  TWaitThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FWaitHandle: THandle;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean; AWaitHandle: THandle);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TWaitThread.Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean; AWaitHandle: THandle);
begin
  inherited Create(ACreateSuspended);
  FWaitHandle := AWaitHandle;
end;

destructor TWaitThread.Destroy; 
begin
  CloseHandle(FWaitHandle);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TWaitThread.Execute; 
begin
  // Ждем завершения процессса
  Win32Check(WaitForSingleObject(FWaitHandle, INFINITE) <> WAIT_FAILED);
end;

// И использование
var
  ..........
  LPI: TProcessInformation;
  LThread: TThread;
begin
  ..........
  Win32Check(CreateProcess(......, LPI));
  CloseHandle(LPI.hThread);
  // Создаем ждущий поток
  LThread := TWaitThread.Create(True, LPI.hProcess);
  // Поток удалится при завершении
  LThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  // После завершения вызвать процедуру EndWait
  LThread.OnTerminate := EndWait;
  // Запускаем поток
  LThread.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.EndWait(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Программа завершена');
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо за решения данного вопроса. Буду теперь оформлять код полностью по данной схеме.

Comment: Последний вопрос, что еще не могу разобрать, почему выделяется вот эта строка: LThread.OnTerminate := EndWait; и пишется undeclared identifier EndWait.

Comment: Так объявите в том классе, где вы создаете поток метод `procedure EndWait(Sender: TObject)`

Comment: Ааааааа, я поняла и сделала, теперь все заработало. Ошибка изначально была в том что я неправильно объявила процедуру..,